# Output of popen() is different from execute "sh -c cmdstring"

Tags: c, unix, pipe

### Description

I tested an example of APUE(Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, 3ed), 15.3 popen and plcose Function.
Example code is as below

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PAGER   "${PAGER:-more}" /* environment variable, or default */

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char    line[MAXLINE];
    FILE    *fpin, *fpout;

    if (argc != 2)
        err_quit("usage: a.out <pathname>");
    if ((fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        err_sys("can't open %s", argv[1]);

    if ((fpout = popen(PAGER, "w")) == NULL)
        err_sys("popen error");

    /* copy argv[1] to pager */
    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fpin) != NULL) {
        if (fputs(line, fpout) == EOF)
            err_sys("fputs error to pipe");
    }
    if (ferror(fpin))
        err_sys("fgets error");
    if (pclose(fpout) == -1)
        err_sys("pclose error");

    exit(0);
}
```

And my input file is "temp.in", we have

```bash
$ cat temp.in
test sentence
```

And the output of example is as below

```bash
$ ./popen2 temp.in 
test sentence
```

### Problem

As showed in APUE, executing `fpout = popen(cmdstring, "w")` is similiar to its child process execute `sh -c cmdstring`. Thus the `popen` of code showed in the last section should execte

```bash
sh -c "${PAGER:-more} test sentence"
```

My OS(Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) doesn't have an environmental value named   `PAGER`, thus it should execute

```bash
sh -c "more test sentence"
```

However, order `more`'s option should be filename as far as I know. Test below order in my system and get the output, which is different from what I inferred above:

```bash
$ ${PAGER:-more} temp.in 
test sentence
$ ${PAGER:-more} test sentence
more: can't open test: no such file or directory
more: can't open sentence: no such file or directory
```

What's wrong with my deduce?

Comment: I don't understand: what is the problem?

Comment: In my opinion, `popen()` in example code should execute `sh -c "${PAGER:-more} test sentence"`,  but that statement would actually report an error.
The right statement should be `sh -c "${PAGER:-more} temp.in"`

Comment: And if *PAGER* is undefined, what would you expect to happen?

Comment: @CristiFati 
```$ echo ${PAGER:-more}
more
```

Comment: Where is `${PAGER:-more} test sentence` coming from? It's not in the argument being passed to `popen()`. It's just executing `${PAGER:-more}`. You're not giving it any other arguments.

Comment: @Shawn You are right, I just searched and tested some code to make it clear.
I reedit my opinion in my question. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Yes, the effect of your code (with popen) is equivalent to the shell command `cat $argv1 | ${PAGER:-more}` which with PAGER unset is the same as `cat $argv1 | more` which works, because like many Unix programs `more` reads from the file(s) named by (non-option) argument(s) if any and if none reads from stdin, which in this case means it reads from the pipe. Where's the confusion?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Get it. Thank you!

Comment: To answer a question, even your own question, post an answer. Do not edit an answer into the question. Then mark the question resolved by accepting the answer, not by editing the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the step by step working principle of `popen()` is as below(we ignore some irrelevant checks):
First: the currency process call `pipe()` to create a pipe

```
int pfd[2];  
pipe(pfd);
```

Second: the current process call `fork()` to create a child process.

```
if (fork() == 0)
    /* child process work */
else if(fork() > 0)
    /* parent process work */
```

Third: the child and parent process close their own fileno to create an unidirectional pipe.
e.d. `popen(cmdstring, "r")`, the parent process close its write fileno, and the child process close its read fileno.

```
/* child process work */
    close(pfd[0]);  // pfd[0] is read port
/* parent process work */
    close(pfd[1]);  // pfd[0] is write port
```

Forth: The parent process and child process redirect their own fileno.
e.d. `popen(cmdstring, "r")`, the parent redirect its `STDIN_FILENO` to read port, and the child process redirect its `STDOUT_FILENO` to write port.

```
/* child process work */
    dup2(pfd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);  
    close(pfd[1]);  
/* parent process work */
    dup2(pfd[0], STDIN_FILENO);  
    close(pfd[0]);
```

Then, the child process could write its output to the pipe, and the parent process could read messages from its child process through its stdin.

Back to the problem. `popen({PAGER:-more}, "w")` connect the currency process's stdout to `more` process's stdin.
Thus `fgets(line, MAXLINE, fpin)` read from `argv[1]` and transfer the string to `more` through pipe, and `more` print it to the terminate. The effect of example is simmiliar to

```bash
cat $argv1 | ${PAGER:-more}
```